# Configuring SVN branches in IntelliJ IDEA 12

Tags: svn, intellij-idea

To begin with: I already consulted JetBrain's [Web Help](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configure-subversion-branches.html) but it did not provide me with any further help.

I am new to IntelliJ IDEA (using 12.1.4) and have some difficulties configuring SVN branches.

My repository's structure is looks about this:

```
/svn.local/some/path/PROJECT/trunk
/svn.local/some/path/PROJECT/branches/dev/{different dev Branches in sub-folders}
/svn.local/some/path/PROJECT/branches/test
/svn.local/some/path/PROJECT/branches/prod
```

As you can see, I have different development branches (each stored in a sub-folder of [..]/branches/dev) but just one test and one prod branch.

My branch configuration works perfectly with the trunk and the dev branches (as there are sub-folders) but not with test and prod.

Is it possible to configure SVN integratoin that I can access test and dev as I am able to do with trunk and dev or would I have to re-structure the whole repository?

Comment: Can you please define what is not working? Is it when you try to check out the branch or after? what error message do u get?

Comment: For example: When selecting TEST or PROD branch I have to select a sub-folder what is not a problem for DEV since the different DEV branches are stored in sub-folders. But in TEST and PROD the sub-folders are already part of the project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you just need to configure multiple branch locations.

In the `Configure Subversion Branches` dialog set values as follows:

```
Trunk location: /svn.local/some/path/PROJECT/trunk
Branch locations:
  /svn.local/some/path/PROJECT/branches
  /svn.local/some/path/PROJECT/branches/dev
```

Now when you select a branch (for example, in the `Update Project` dialog) you should have the following options:

```
trunk (trunk)
branches...
dev...
```

Select `branches..` and this should give you this list:

```
test
prod
dev
```

Now you can select either of your `test` or `prod` branches, which is what you want. Of course, `dev` really shouldn't be in this list, but since you've got branches nested in a subfolder of the `branches` folder, intellij thinks `dev` is also a branch here. However, selecting `dev...` from the previous step gives you access to your other branches too.